# MauiApp crashes only in release mode at sideswitch android.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: android, xaml, crash, maui

I have a Mauiapp which I debug and test on a physical android device. All the time I had no problems but now when I switch to two sides in my app it crashes. The crash only appears in release mode and not while debuging. As mentioned it crashes only for two sides from the flyoutmenu all other sides and flyoutmenu sides work perfektly.

I don't really now what to do because I don't have any error messages or hints where the error appears.

I allready tried to delete obj and bin folder or to clean and rebuild the project.

If you need any parts of the code or something else please write a comment and thanks for your help!

UPDATE

After using Logcat I found these entries which could be a good clue:

[image]

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-31 10:39:49.845  Samsung SM-A546E    Verbose 1310    WindowManager   Setting visibility of Window{d8681d9 u0 com.engelberthdeveloping.passwortapp/crc6451514aa4f2d5798b.MainActivity EXITING}: false, caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.sendAppVisibilityToClients:1281 com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.setClientVisible:447 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.setClientVisible:7988 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation:6593 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.commitVisibility:6536 

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-31 10:39:49.845  Samsung SM-A546E    Warning 1310    WindowManager   Exception thrown during dispatchAppVisibility Window{d8681d9 u0 com.engelberthdeveloping.passwortapp/crc6451514aa4f2d5798b.MainActivity EXITING}

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-31 10:39:49.845  Samsung SM-A546E    Warning 1310    WindowManager   android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:662)
    at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.dispatchAppVisibility(IWindow.java:631)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowState.java:3982)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowContainer.java:1281)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.setClientVisible(WindowToken.java:447)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.setClientVisible(ActivityRecord.java:7988)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation(ActivityRecord.java:6593)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.commitVisibility(ActivityRecord.java:6536)
    at com.android.server.wm.Transition.finishTransition(Transition.java:1400)
    at com.android.server.wm.TransitionController.finishTransition(TransitionController.java:1036)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowOrganizerController.finishTransition(WindowOrganizerController.java:429)
    at android.window.IWindowOrganizerController$Stub.onTransact(IWindowOrganizerController.java:286)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowOrganizerController.onTransact(WindowOrganizerController.java:207)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1380)

    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311)

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-31 10:39:49.845  Samsung SM-A546E    Info    1310    Process Sending signal. PID: 28268 SIG: 9

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-31 10:39:49.846  Samsung SM-A546E    Verbose 1310    WindowManager   Remove Window{d8681d9 u0 com.engelberthdeveloping.passwortapp/crc6451514aa4f2d5798b.MainActivity EXITING}: mSurfaceController=Surface(name=com.engelberthdeveloping.passwortapp/crc6451514aa4f2d5798b.MainActivity$_28268)/@0x3fdc60a mAnimatingExit=true mRemoveOnExit=true mHasSurface=true surfaceShowing=true animating=false app-animation=false mDisplayFrozen=false callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.removeAllWindowsIfPossible:258 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.removeIfPossible:5063 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.handleCompleteDeferredRemoval:5070 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.handleCompleteDeferredRemoval:1456 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.handleCompleteDeferredRemoval:3345 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.handleCompleteDeferredRemoval:1456 

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-31 10:39:49.847  Samsung SM-A546E    Info    1310    WindowManager   Destroying surface Surface(name=com.engelberthdeveloping.passwortapp/crc6451514aa4f2d5798b.MainActivity$_28268)/@0x3fdc60a called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:789 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:472 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:2904 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:3140 com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.removeAllWindowsIfPossible:258 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.removeIfPossible:5063 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onRemovedFromDisplay:5145 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.removeImmediately:5053
```

Comment: Do you have any exception handling or crash reporting in your app?

Comment: I have exception handling but nothing reacts. As I mentioned I don't get any error while debuging. First I thought it is an error with the release version, but when I start the debug version on my phone without debuging on the pc it crashes also.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to debug against **release mode** on your physical device.

That or, you can run **logcat** on terminal, while your app is running (on release mode), and see what errors come up. You should see the exceptions, and stack trace.

Please post them on your question, so the community can help. Thanks

**UPDATE**

**To enable debugging on release mode** simply go to your project's properties and go here:
[image]

**You can also enable CLR Exceptions, so that Visual studio will show you, where the error actually came from while debugging**
[image]

Then just enable **CLR Exceptions**

Comment: How do I debug against release mode?

Comment: Just change your config to release mode on Visual Studio, then deploy to your device. Just make sure release mode has "debugging" enabled, so visual studio will include the PDBs. If that doesn't work, you can run it against logcat directly via terminal as I described in the answer above (just run the app on your device as normal, you don't need the IDE for this)

Comment: Also, make sure you go to Debug -> Exceptions -> Enable Common Exceptions (You should see the reason for the crash come up)

Comment: Where do I check that debugging is enabled? How do I start the app, on release mode in vs as normal or what else?

Comment: If that doesn't work (if no exception comes up), please just run the logcat via terminal, and run the app. Then post the logs on your question so I can help

Comment: I found some messages and added them to the question